# My Juniper SRX System-Retry-Options not works, Why?

Tags: firewall, gateway, juniper, brute-force

I have a Juniper-SRX and I want to configure its *System-Retry-Options* in a way that after `5` unsuccessful attempts to logins for a particular username the device gets locked for the user for `4` minutes.So I followed the instruction that is mentioned in this [website](http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB28968&actp=RSS).

After that, I checked *System-Retry-Options* to see if the settings changed or not :

```
root@host# show system login retry-options
tries-before-disconnect 5;
backoff-threshold 3;
backoff-factor 10;
lockout-period 4;

[edit]
```

As you see above, I set the right settings. So if I have `5` failed attempts (or more) to login, It must lock for `4` minutes.

I was wanted to test it. So I opened my web-browser and entered my SRX IP address and try to login 6 times with a single username and different wrong passwords.

[image]

In this moment I except it to be lock for 4 minutes, but when I try it with correct password, It logged in!

**Is there something wrong with my SRX or its settings? Why it didn't locked for 4 minutes?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer in Juniper facebook page. These setting are for SSH and Telnet. And they don't work in http. Just this!